# Syntax hightlighting of template-toolkit within Ultraedit

Tags: syntax-highlighting, template-toolkit, ultraedit

Have anyone succesfully created a "wordfile" that works? I've tried but i can't get it to highlight [% and %]

Answer (score 2):

I am much too late to answer this, just was looking for some help with my wordfile problem and came across your unanswered question.  After fighting several hours with my wordfile I thought this should be fairly easy to complete now, so here is a wordfile I was able to get working to highlight your special "words":

```
/L19"Test" nocase Line Comment = ! String Chars = '" File Extensions = test
/Colors = 0,8421376,8421376,8421504,255,
/Colors Back = 16777215,16777215,16777215,16777215,16777215,
/Colors Auto Back = 1,1,1,1,1,
/Font Style = 0,0,0,0,0,
/Delimiters = ~!@^&*()_-+=|\/{}:;"'<> , .?
/C1 Colors = 8421376 Colors Back = 16777215 Colors Auto Back = 1 Font Style = 0
%]
[%
```

Probably lots in there you don't care about, special things I came across:

1. It appears the lines for the different colors have to be sorted by the first character and each new character should be on a new line.
2. Since you are trying to put special characters as words, I removed them from the "Delimiters" line - maybe this is a problem.
3. When saving the uew file, make sure the newline character is correct for the OS you are working on, the file I started with was a unix file and I am working on a windows box.  Once I saved my file converting the line endings to windows, it worked perfectly.

Well, sorry for being so late to answer your question.  I don't normally watch the UltraEdit tag, but do like the tool.